# Fooling System.Diagnostics.Process WaitForExit()

Tags: c#, python, process, mono, system.diagnostics

There is a program (c#) that starts my script via System.Diagnostics.Process and then calls WaitForExit() on it. The script (python in this case, though could be anything) then spawns a child process and exits. I expected the program to continue, but it hangs until the child process exits.

I have tried many ways of starting subprocesses, from python's os.fork to writing a shell script wrapper, but every method causes the program to hang. I can't change the code of the c# program, what do I need to do to the child process to allow the program to continue?

Note: I do not know if it matters, but the c# program is running in mono on ubuntu.

Edit: After further review of the c# code right before WaitForExit is call there is a `while (!process.StandardOutput.EndOfStream)` loop, could this be the problem?

Comment: Do you have control over the subprocess's code, or do you have to do this from within your middle Python script?

Comment: I have control of both. In fact my os.fork method used a single Python script.

Comment: OK, that should be even easier… let me edit the answer.

Comment: As a side note, do you know if there's any good documentation on how mono maps .NET process semantics onto POSIX process semantics? I couldn't find anything useful in a search.

Comment: I'm not really a c# programmer, so no, I don't know of any.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WaitForExit seems to hang on open stdout/stderr. I used this script to make my script async:

```
#!/bin/bash

~/foo.py "$@" >&- 2>&- &
```

Hope this helps the next person to come along.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to do this is to have the child process `setsid()`, which will remove all of its connections to you—it becomes a session leader of a new session, and a group leader of a new process group, and detaches from your stdio, all in one call.

If you can't modify the child process's code, you can do it from your Python parent by explicitly [`fork`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.fork)ing, then calling [`setsid`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.setsid), then [`exec`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.execv)ing, instead of the various usual cleaner methods like `subprocess`. Like this:

```
pid = os.fork()
if not pid:
    sid = os.setsid()
    os.execv(path, args)
```

---

I believe it's the process group that matters to `System.Diagnostics.Process`, but I don't actually know that for sure, so I figured better to be safe than sorry. If you want to try just `os.setpgrp()`, you can try it. If that works, you can actually `spawn`/`subprocess`/etc. the child and then just `setpgid(pid, pid)` on it.

---

Meanwhile, it sounds like you're just `fork`ing a child and continuing the same script in that child, in which case you can just add the `setsid` (or maybe `setpgrp`) after the `fork` and you should be done.

Comment: I tried something similar (that did not work), see https://gist.github.com/RedHatter/8264094 would this do the same thing?

Comment: Yeah, that ought to work; not sure why it doesn't. It's possible that you need to synchronize on something so the parent can wait for the child to detach before exiting?

Comment: Hmm... I'm not really sure how to do that.

Comment: I added a sleep statement before the parent exits, but it did not change anything. Therefore I do not think its a synchronization problem.

Comment: This does not work on OSX using a .Net project calling a process which is a python file that spawns a subprocess. The WaitForExit in the C# code hangs forever until the forked subprocess is exited.